# Joining tables on an array with string

Tags: sql, arrays, join

I am looking to do a left join on a table that has an array column called tags with a table that has the definitions of the tag, tag_definitions. There will only be one (at the most) match per row in the Cities Table. I can't join an array with a string and i'm not sure how to proceed.

Cities_Table

> City_Code  | State   |Tags
>
> NYC | NY | 1, 4, 5
>
> SF | CA | 2,4, 6
>
> CHI | IL | 3, 8, 10

.

Tag_Definitions

> Tag_ID | Name
>
> 5 | East_Coast
>
> 6 | West_Coast
>
> 10 | MidWest

So I'm looking to get something like this...

> City_Code  | State   |Tags | Tag_Descr
>
> NYC | NY | 1, 4, 5 | East_Coast
>
> SF | CA | 2,4, 6 | West_Coast
>
> CHI | IL | 3, 8, 10 | MidWest

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Fix your data structure to use a junction table rather than storing lists of numeric tag ids in a string.

Comment: where are  your tag descriptions for 1, 2, 3, 8 ? how do you know that for 1, 4, 5 the tag_descr is East_Coast ? because 1 could be West_Coast or South_Coast ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database (the syntax might be different), you can do something like the following:

```
select *
from cities_table c 
  join tag_definitions t on concat(',',c.tags,',') like concat('%,',t.tag_id,',%')
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/691fb5/3)

However as noted, a better idea would be to create a `City_Tags` table and store the individual ids in that table.  Generally it's not a good idea to store comma delimited data.